# Hadoop MapReduce from CSV to the Gigaspace

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I need to resolve next task - from external source many *.csv files writes to the HDFS. After that I need to execute MapReduce for write this files to the Gigaspaces. Hadoop have standart Mapper for the csv files or I need to use custom?

Comment: Have you tried passing it in as a string (by line), and simply using `String.split(",");` ? That would seem to be the easiest way to get this done. If that is not a workable solution please explain why not.

Comment: I need to get this as file, not a String. Maybe - Hadoop have Mapper for csv out of the box?

Comment: @VladislavLysov: So you don't want to parse the data in file rather just write(copy?) the files to Gigaspaces using MapReduce?

Comment: @VladislavLysov : simply copying files is really not a task that mapreduce is made for. You would basically have to set the number of mappers and reducers to 1 and copy line by line. Doing it with multiple mappers may very well scramble the order. While this is doable, in the vast majority of circumstances where you need to copy are better served by other methods. A non-mapreduce Java program could probably do the task with much less effort, or perhaps a script.